# Вместо русских букв пишет ерунду в оконной программе написанной в rubymine

Tags: ruby

```
require 'Qt4'

class Test<Qt::TextEdit

    def keyPressEvent(e)

        if(e.key()==Qt::Key_Enter || e.key()==Qt::Key_Return)
            text=$ptxt2.toPlainText()
            $ptxt1.setPlainText(text)

        else
            super
        end

    end

end



app = Qt::Application.new(ARGV)

$ptxt1=Test.new
$ptxt2=Test.new
$ptxt3=Test.new
$ptxt4=Test.new

spl1=Qt::Splitter.new(Qt.Horizontal)
spl3=Qt::Splitter.new(Qt.Vertical,spl1)
spl4=Qt::Splitter.new(Qt.Vertical,spl1)

spl3.addWidget($ptxt1)
spl3.addWidget($ptxt2)
spl4.addWidget($ptxt3)
spl4.addWidget($ptxt4)


font = Qt::Font.new
font.family = "Courier New"
font.pointSize = 12
font.bold = true
font.weight = 75


$ptxt1.font = font
$ptxt2.font = font
$ptxt3.font = font
$ptxt4.font = font

$ptxt2.setFocus

spl1.resize(500, 500)
spl1.show()
spl3.show()
app.exec()
```

Пробовал менять кодировки, ничего не получилось. Нужно чтобы русский текст написанный в одном окне ($ptxt2) корректно выводился в другом окне ($ptxt1).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42793/discussion-on-question-by---------).

Comment: Не надо было целиком дискуссию мигрировать -- уточнение про Windows пригодились бы на этой странице.